is there a function $\phi$ such that $\int_R \int_R f(t)g(s)\phi(t,s)dsdt=\int_Rf(t)g(t)\rho(t)dt $?
Let $\rho$ be a positive function, is there exist a function $\phi$ such that for any $f,g$:
$$\int_R \int_R f(t)g(s)\phi(t,s)dsdt=\int_Rf(t)g(t)\rho(t)dt $$
of course both integrals are supposed finite here.

Formally, let $(\psi_n)$ be an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\rho)$. Then $\phi(t,s)=\sum_n \psi_n(t)\psi_n(s)\rho(t)\rho(s)$ would work.

Yeah , but I guess instead of $\rho$ you should put $\sqrt(\rho)$ ?! @Julius

I believe $\rho$ is the correct factor to include, since the $f$ and $g$ themselves dont contribute any factor of $\rho$. In any case, the expression is only formal and one must check convergence of the series.

Can you please me give some condition on $\rho$ such that the above series converge ?@Julius
